# Webpack dynamic import within any loop

Tags: javascript, webpack

I checked the webpack documentation and did not find any examples. What I want is to dynamically import data from the API.

Example:

```
var components = []
data.forEach(component => {
    components.push({
        component: () => import(`@/views/` + component)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `require`.

```
var components = []
data.forEach(component => {
    components.push({
        component: require(`@/views/` + component)
    })
})
```